# Discrete Mathematics Nonhomogenous linear recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Solve the recurrence relation

$$a_n=-a_{n-1}+8a_{n-1}+12a_{n-3}+25\cdot3^{n-2}-18n^2+48n+14\text{ for }n\ge3$$ where $a_0=6,a_1=0$ and $a_2=57$.

Just want to ask if my $p_n$ is correct because I just can't get the value of A. I have deduced $p_n$ = $A3^{n-2}-Bn^2+Cn+D$. Where $a_n = b_n + p_n$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Thanks for your question.  Just a couple tips:  First of all, in general try to use MathJax formatting to make the question a little more clear.  Secondly, it might be a bit easier for readers if you include the question in your post as opposed to in a link.  Good luck!

Comment: You are looking for a particular solution, I think. Because $3$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, one component  of the particular solution will be a term of the shape $An3^n$. Note that this comment just deals with your first term of the particular solution.

Comment: To repeat, the thing to try is $A(n3^n)$. There is no need for a $K(3^n)$ term, when you push that through the recurrence, you get no information.

Comment: The second term on the right hand side of the recurrence relation should be $8a_{n-2}$, not $8a_{n-1}$ as it is now, I believe. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the shift operator acting on the two-way infinite sequences $x=(x_n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z})$,
\begin{equation*}
(Ex)_n=x_{n+1}~,
\end{equation*}
and $\Delta=E-1$ the difference operator,
\begin{equation*}
(\Delta x)_n=x_{n+1}-x_n~.
\end{equation*}
The given recurrence relation (which works also backwards for $n<0$, that is, it determines the values of $a_n$ for all integers $n$)
\begin{gather*}
a_n=-a_{n-1}+8a_{n-2}+12a_{n-3}+25\cdot3^{n-2}-18n^2+48n+14~, \\[1ex]
a_0=6\,,~a_1=0\,,~a2=57~,
\end{gather*}
we rewrite in the form
\begin{equation*}
((E^3+E^2-8E-12)a)_{n-3}=25\cdot3^{n-2}-18n^2+48n+14~,
\end{equation*}
where $E^3+E^2-8E-12$ factors as $(E+2)^2(E-3)$. We know that $E-3$ kills $3^{n-2}$ and that $\Delta^3$ kills every polynomial in $n$ of degree at most two,
therefore the sequence $a=(a_n)$ satisfies the homogeneous recurrence relation
\begin{equation*}
(E-1)^3(E+2)^2(E-3)^2x=0~,
\end{equation*}
(with $x=a$) which has the general solution of the form
\begin{equation*}
x_n = \alpha_0+\alpha_1n+\alpha_2n^2 + (\beta_0+\beta_1n)\cdot(-2)^n+(\gamma_0+\gamma_1n)\cdot3^n~.
\end{equation*}
All it remains to do is to compute $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$, $a_6$ using the given recurrence relation and then solve the seven linear equations $x_k=a_k$, $0\leq k\leq 6$, for the seven unknowns $\alpha_0$, $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, $\gamma_0$, $\gamma_1$, which gets us
\begin{equation*}
\alpha_0=0\,,~\alpha_1=3\,,~\alpha_2=1\,,~\beta_0=5\,,~\beta_1=0\,,\gamma_0=1\,,\gamma_1=1\,.
\end{equation*}
So we have the explicit expression for $a_n$:
\begin{equation*}
a_n \,=\, 3n+n^2+5\cdot(-2)^n+(1+n)\cdot3^n~.
\end{equation*}
Done.